# Pandas datetime64 with longer range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame with datetime values spanning from year 1 to way into future. When I try to import the data into pandas the dtype gets set to `object` although I would like it to be datetime64 to use the `.dt` accessor.

Consider this piece of code:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': [datetime(108, 7, 30, 9, 25, 27, tzinfo=pytz.utc),
                             datetime(2018, 3, 20, 9, 25, 27, tzinfo=pytz.utc),
                             datetime(2529, 7, 30, 9, 25, 27, tzinfo=pytz.utc)]})
In [5]: df.dates
Out[5]: 
0    0108-07-30 09:25:27+00:00
1    2018-03-20 09:25:27+00:00
2    2529-07-30 09:25:27+00:00
Name: dates, dtype: object
```

How can I convert it to dtype `datetime64[s]`? I don't really care about nano/millisecond accuracy, but I would like the range.

Comment: `df['dates']=pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format=' ')`

Comment: Unless they've added it since I last dealt with this, Pandas's built-in conversion to/from `datetime.datetime` doesn't work with tz-aware datetime objects, so you can't do this. But since your objects are UTC, that shouldn't be a problem—just create UTC datetimes instead of tz-aware datetime objects imbued with the UTC timezone.

Comment: But anyway, this still won't work, because 64-bit nanoseconds can't span a range as wide as you want; they can only handle a bit over 584 years. I can't remember where Pandas puts the boundaries, but I can look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas can generally convert to and from `datetime.datetime` objects:

```
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)
```

But in your case, you can't do this, for two reasons.

First, while Pandas can convert to and from `datetime.datetime`, it can't handle tz-aware `datetime`s, and you've imbued yours with a timezone. Fortunately, this one is easy to fix—you're explicitly using UTC, and you can do that without aware objects.

Second, 64-bit nanoseconds can't handle a date range as wide as you want:

```
>>> (1<<64) / / 1000000000 / 3600 / 24 / 365.2425
584.5540492538555
```

And [the Pandas documentation makes this clear](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations):

> Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the time span that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years:

```
In [66]: pd.Timestamp.min
Out[66]: Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')

In [67]: pd.Timestamp.max
Out[67]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

(It looks like they put the 0 point at the Unix epoch, which makes sense.)

But notice that the documentation links to [Representing Out-of-Bounds Spans](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob): you *can* use `Period`s, which will be less efficient and convenient than int64s, but probably more so than `object`s. (I believe the internal storage ends up being YYYYMMDD-style strings, but they're stored as fixed-length strings directly in the array, instead of as references to Python objects on the heap.)